# What does the %12.10lg means in C++ strings formatting

Tags: c++, windows

I have seen this piece of code in one of the C++ project in windows environment. just wondering what does the meaning of `%12.10lg`. Anyone has idea?

```
class Point 
{
 double x, y;
 public Point::Point(double x_cord, double y_cord)
 {
  x = x_cord;
  y = y_cord;
 }
}

void foo(){
  Point ptStart(12.5, 33.5678)
  TRACE("%12.10lg, %12.10lg, %12.10lg\n", ptStart)
}
```

Comment: Probably a project extension to string substitution.  You should look in (give us a look at) the source of the `TRACE` macro.

Comment: That looks like a pretty standard printf style format string. The % tells it to do a variable substitution. The "lg" is a bit strange, but 'g' means the variable is a double (which is it) and the l prefix might be a platform way of specifying long. "12.10" means to display up to 12 digits before the decimal point and up to 10 digits after.

Comment: @Chris, yes, `lg` makes it a `long double` as per [Size Specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6.aspx) on MSDN.  Apparently it doesn't actually make any difference, the internal representation is the same.

Answer (score 4):

`TRACE` probably uses the normal format specifiers which then means that `%12.10lg` should print out a `double` value with a minimum width of 12 and a precision of 10, something like : `15.8930000000`.

Comment: Gill: any idea what would be the output in this case?

Answer (score 2):

To display messages from your program in the debugger Output window, you can use the ATLTRACE macro or the MFC TRACE macro. Like assertions, the trace macros are active only in the Debug version of your program and disappear when compiled in the Release version. Like printf, the TRACE macro can handle a number of arguments.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wyz8787(v=vs.80).aspx

In your particular case, `"%12.10lg"` is a string similar to what you'd see in [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

printf uses this format:
`%[flags][width][.precision][length]specifier`
In your case:

```
flags = unused
width = 12
precision = 10
length=long int 
specifier=short representation
```

When you print this, it'll print the following arguments (ptStart)

Comment: Thank you for nice explanation . So what would be the output in this case. I'm thinking why same string three times and how does ptStart cast to get the output?

Comment: @Nayana, I suspect that's a bug in the code you're looking at.  The number of specifiers should match the number of arguments.  (It is possible that passing a structure is equivalent in this context to passing the elements of the structure, I'm not sure.  But even then you should only have two specifiers in the format string, not three.)